# SharePoint News Web-part

Tags: modern-pages

1)Is it possible to remove "Created By" in the "News from sites" tile on SharePoint Home Page?
​

2)We created different sites to Post news articles and in Home Page we added those different news sites by selecting option "select sites" News web part Modern Page SharePoint Online But we are unable to add inline News post  In the Home-Page itself.
So can we add Inline news Post directly to the Homepage instead of going to that particular individual sites and adding news Post?

Could you tell us when is you available time so we can connect?